# How to refactor this code OOP code for an interview?

Tags: oop

So I was asked to refactor this code in an interview

There is a `Shape` abstract class. `Square`, `Rectangle` which are derived classes of `Shape`. `Square` and `Rectangle` override the method `area()` of `Shape`. Now how do I refactor code something like this?

```
if(object is of type Square) {
    //call area on square
} else if (object is of type Rectangle) {
   //call area of rectangle
} else if(object of type Cube) {
  // call volume of cube
}...
.
.
.
```

The question was basically how do you avoid multiple if conditions since there can be lot of derived classes and call the appropriate method on that object?

Comment: Where does `Cube` come from? What is its relation with the other types?

Comment: Cube could also derive from Shape. Overriding area to give Volume of the cube.

Comment: So is "volume" a different method or is it also the "area" method? Because this could be a simple case of polymorphism: just call `area()` on whatever shape is passed, you don't have to look at the exact implementation.

Comment: Downvoter. Please comment on what you are expecting. I will answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Since this question was asked in an interview I might not be able to give more than what was asked. I did not do great obviously asking more about this question. I just gave up but now I would like to know what is usually an accepted answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah now I understand
what he wanted to hear was probably that you can add another abstract class, say, AbstractFlatShapes

then check

```
if (object is instance of AbstractFlatShapes){
//call area
}else{
//call volume
}
```

to make myself clear

`AbstractFlatShapes` extends `Shape`
i am quite sure he wanted to hear that. Just imagine there are 15 flat shapes, and you do `else if` for each shape? to call the same function.

Comment: let me wait to see if there are any more answers since this is bit open ended. If not will accept yours as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a [`switch`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)—like this example from PHP—would be a good answer?

```
switch (object) {
    case Square:
        // call area on square
        break;
    case Rectangle:
        // call area of rectangle
        break;
    case Cube:
        // call volume of cube
        break;
}
```

Comment: I thought the interviewer was expecting something in the lines of Switch statement but I did not know what to answer. I just replied I don't know and we moved to next question.

Comment: switch and if else are pretty much identical. I mean, i would never refactor something like this, a simple waste of time

Answer (score 0):

I think the bigger problem with that code is handling two different things in one method: area and volume. So later on in the code it has to check whether the object was a 2-d shape or a 3-d shape yet again since you most likely can't handle area and volume as the same. The shape classes should each implement the methods for whatever purpose it was to get area and volume in the first place